# How can I sum population of all city in every utility(XML data) using c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DetailedUtilityCollection SchemaVersion="1.0">
<DetailedUtility UtilityId="720" UtilityName="Chelan County Public Utility District" CountryCode="US" StateCode="WA">
  <Rate Id="2350" Name="Residential Service (Schedule 1)" Sector="Residential" Metering="OptionalNetMetering" IsDefault="true" IsTimeOfUse="false" />
  <Rate Id="2351" Name="General Service - Nondemand (Schedule 2)" Sector="Commercial" Metering="OptionalNetMetering" IsDefault="true" IsTimeOfUse="false" />
  <Rate Id="2352" Name="General Service - Demand (Schedule 2)" Sector="Commercial" Metering="OptionalNetMetering" IsDefault="false" IsTimeOfUse="false" />
  <City Name="Cashmere" Population="7233">
     <CityLocation Zip="98815" Lat="47.53593" Lng="-120.494571" />
  </City>
  <City Name="Chelan" Population="6394">
     <CityLocation Zip="98816" Lat="47.901204" Lng="-120.139618" />
  </City>
  <City Name="Entiat" Population="1953">
     <CityLocation Zip="98822" Lat="47.885389" Lng="-120.47078" />
  </City>
  <City Name="Leavenworth" Population="6504">
     <CityLocation Zip="98826" Lat="47.82259" Lng="-120.825267" />
  </City>
  <City Name="Wenatchee" Population="40977">
     <CityLocation Zip="98801" Lat="47.451974" Lng="-120.330783" />
     <CityLocation Zip="98802" Lat="47.494001" Lng="-120.193856" />
     <CityLocation Zip="98807" Lat="47.4236" Lng="-120.3092" />
  </City>
  <City Name="West Wenatchee" Population="40977">
     <CityLocation Zip="98801" Lat="47.451974" Lng="-120.330783" />
  </City>
  </DetailedUtility>
  <DetailedUtility UtilityId="721" UtilityName="Clallam County PUD" CountryCode="US" StateCode="WA">
  <Rate Id="2353" Name="General Service - Residential, Farm (Schedule E-4)" Sector="Residential" Metering="OptionalNetMetering" IsDefault="true" IsTimeOfUse="false" />
  <Rate Id="2354" Name="General Service - Commercial (Schedule E-4)" Sector="Commercial" Metering="OptionalNetMetering" IsDefault="true" IsTimeOfUse="false" />
  <Rate Id="2355" Name="Large Power Service (Schedule E-5)" Sector="Commercial" Metering="OptionalNetMetering" IsDefault="false" IsTimeOfUse="false" />
  <City Name="Forks" Population="6261">
     <CityLocation Zip="98331" Lat="47.851473" Lng="-124.28411" />
  </City>
  <City Name="Neah Bay" Population="1414">
     <CityLocation Zip="98357" Lat="48.332856" Lng="-124.639563" />
  </City>
  <City Name="Port Angeles" Population="22230">
     <CityLocation Zip="98362" Lat="47.99614" Lng="-123.38281" />
     <CityLocation Zip="98363" Lat="48.017263" Lng="-123.824588" />
  </City>
  <City Name="Port Angeles East" Population="-1" />
  <City Name="Sequim" Population="26856">
     <CityLocation Zip="98382" Lat="48.025762" Lng="-123.061784" />
  </City>
  </DetailedUtility>
  </DetailedUtilityCollection>
```

How can I get sum of all city population in every utilityid in c#. Please help me.

I've tried following codes but none is working for me.

```
xmlDoc.LoadXml(strFetchResData);

                        //dynamic BillUtilityData = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc).Replace(@"@", @"").Remove(1, 44);
                        //dynamic BillUtilityData  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc).Replace(@"@", @"").Remove(1, 44));
                        //dynamic BillUtilityData = JsonString;
                        XmlNodeList utilitylist = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;

                        if (utilitylist.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (XmlNode nodeUtil in utilitylist)
                            {
                                double? totalPopulation = 0;
                                //xmlDoc.Load(nodeUtil.InnerXml.ToString());
                                dynamic BillUtilityData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(nodeUtil).Replace(@"@", @"").Remove(1, 44));
                                //totalPopulation = Convert.ToDouble((nodeUtil).LastChild.Attributes["Population"].Value);
                                //xmlDoc.LoadXml(nodeUtil.InnerText);


                                //foreach (XmlNode cityUtil in nodeUtil["City"])
                                //{
                                //    totalPopulation = SunpowerServiceMethods.calculateTotalPopulationOfCitySiblings(cityUtil,totalPopulation);
                                //    break;
                                //}

                            }
```

Comment: What happens when the code doesn't work? Does it compile? Do you get run-time errors? Do you get the wrong answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Thus your [real](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0Oyteicy-mANnBoX1FIRmNmMnM/edit) XML file has namespaces declared, you should deal with them.

I suggest you to use LINQ to XML. With [Enumerable.Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for each utility element select sum of it's cities population:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var query = from u in xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "DetailedUtility")
            select new
            {
                UtilityId = (int)u.Attribute("UtilityId"),
                TotalPopulation = u.Elements(ns + "City")
                                   .Sum(c => (int)c.Attribute("Population"))
            };
```

Returns:

```
{ UtilityId = 720, TotalPopulation = 104038 }
{ UtilityId = 721, TotalPopulation = 56760 }
```

Comment: XDocument.Load(path_to_xml) expects URI but I'm having one string in xml format. how can I insert my xml string in xdoc variable?

Comment: @SumitChourasia just use `XDocument.Parse` instead of `XDocument.Load`

Comment: How to get the values of each UtilityId and it's total Population?
foreach loop is giving error

Comment: @SumitChourasia foreach should work `foreach(var item in query) { // use item.TotalPopulation }`

Comment: @SumitChourasia, if you are getting an error, you should tell the people helping you exactly what that error is!

Comment: I'm getting null in variable "query" so foreach is not executed even for once. I'm unable to fix it yet.

Comment: @SumitChourasia make sure you have exactly same xml, without any namespaces or additional elements in hierarchy. I verified my query on your xml, it works fine and produces results which I copy-pasted here

Comment: Can you test on this XML structure
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wJDz_HjDA4wRgkZVN9zt4PmjE1WCgIujk2zoNNn9rxE/edit?usp=sharing

this is the exact structure from which I need total population but it is giving null result.
Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: @SumitChourasia like I suggested, you have namespaces in your real xml. Please, next time provide your *real* xml to avoid such issues. I have updated code to deal with namespace

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
    var xml = "all your xml";
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //or XDocument.Load for loading from a stream
    var sum = doc.Root.Elements("DetailedUtility").Select(element => new
    {
        Id = element.Attribute("UtilityId"),
        Population = element.Elements("City").Sum(e => int.Parse(e.Attribute("Population").Value))
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this piece of code. It works fine. Let me know if u face any issues.

> ```
>  XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("D:\\population.xml");
>         List<string> Utility_id = new List<string>();
>         List<int> population = new List<int>();
>         int i=0;            
>         while (reader.Read())
>         {
>             if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
>             {
>                 if (reader.Name == "DetailedUtility")
>                 {
>                     Utility_id.Add(reader.GetAttribute(0));
>                     population.Add(0);
>                     i++;
>                 }
>                 if (reader.Name == "City")
>                 {
>                     population[i-1] += Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetAttribute(1));
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         for (i = 0; i < Utility_id.Count; i++)
>         {
>             Console.WriteLine("Utility ID = " + Utility_id[i] + "\t Population = " + population[i]);
>         }
>             Console.ReadLine();
> ```

Regards,
Prajul G